# Copy an Array without doubles in PseudoCode

Tags: python, pseudocode

I'm trying to copy an array of values to another array and removing the double values in an natural order (so the 0 values to the end of the array). **I have to put in pseudocode so I can't use easy functions or methods**.

To check my ideas I tried it in Python like this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
B = [0 for b in range(12)]


for i in range(12):

 if  A[i]== A[i-1]: 

 else:
    B[i] = A[i]

print(B)
```

it gives me:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

but the result I'm looking for is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0 , 0]
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `i` is always incrementing, so each iteration, whether you copied an element or not, will handle the next element in `B`.

You can keep track of how many elements you skipped, and use it to access B in the correct index:

```py
skipped = 0
for i in range(12):
 if  A[i] == A[i-1]:
     skipped += 1
 else:
    B[i-skipped] = A[i]
```

Output of `print(B)`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion; arrays are called lists in Python.

Your code checks the values in the list in both positions and replaces it or not. That's where your result comes from. Let's first simplify a bit

```
for i in range(12):
    if not A[i] == A[i - 1]:
        B[i] = A[i]
print(B)
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So I'm not sure if you really want these trailing zeros, because if you don't you can just use the data type `set()` which will only store the unique values, then you can convert it back to list using list(), like so:

```
print(list(set(A)))
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Hi Herman, thanks for the answer. Ah i tried python the first time coming from Java .. i know arrays and lists.. sorry :D But actually yes, i wanted to see the trailing zeros here. But its nice to see there is a solution who pops them out.